# Подсчет данных из таблицы со связями М-М mysql

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Приложение на Laravel 5.6.

Есть таблицы `orders, products, order_products`. В таблице `order_products` есть поля `order_id, product_id, price, count`. Вопрос: каким образом я могу получить список заказов (Orders) с их суммами через Eloquent?

Базовые отношения прописаны:

```
class Order extends Model
{
  public function products() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_products')
                   ->withPivot('count', 'price', 'amount');
   }
}

class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если реализовать ваш запрос на sql, то получится что-то вроде:

```
select * from orders join (
    select order_id, sum(price) * count as sum from order_products group by order_id
) op on orders.id = op.order_id
```

Это можно реализовать с помощь `Order::query()` и `join()`, но это будет сильно влиять на производительность и, в случае, если вы захотите использовать пагинацию, то, для оптимизации, в подзапрос нужно будет вставить `where order_id IN (order1, order2, .., orderN)`, перед этим выполнив ещё один запрос, получающий `id` заказов.

Это не очень оптимальный подход, вариантом будет добавление ещё одного поля `total_sum` в `orders`, в которое будет записываться сумма всего заказа при добавлении или удалении товаров.

Answer (score 0):

```
$orders = Order::leftJoin('order_products', 'order_products.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
     ->select('orders.*', DB::raw( 'sum( order_products.price * order_products.count) as `total`' ) )
     ->groupBy('orders.id')
     ->orderBy('total', 'DSC')
     ->get();
```

Comment: Да, это уже сделал. Но не до конца понимаю, как сделать, чтобы получать цену по запросу `$orders = Order::all()`, т.е. куда именно это добавить? В глобальный скоп выносить нужно, как я понимаю, верно?

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае, возможно будет лучше с коррелирующим подзапросом:

```
select o.*, (
    select sum(price) * count 
    from order_products op 
    group by order_id
    o.id = op.order_id) as sum 
from orders o
```