# Поиск через where при использовании sum - mysql

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Всем привет. Данный вопрос - дополнение вопроса [Подсчет данных из таблицы со связями М-М mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/858497/).

Вводные данные:

Таблицы `orders, products, order_products`. В таблице `order_products` есть поля `order_id, product_id, price, count`. Я получаю поле `total` через использование `sum()`, получается следующий запрос:

```
select `orders`.*, 
sum( order_products.price * order_products.count) as `total` 
  from `orders` 
left join `order_products` 
  on `order_products`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
where `id` = 2 
group by `orders`.`id`
```

Вопрос именно в использовании `where` для поля `total`. Если я добавлю в запрос во `where` следующее: `where 'total' > 1000`, я получу ошибку, мол, поля total не существует. Да, самого поля не существует, но получаемые данные-то есть. Как мне использовать `where` в данном случае?

Answer (score 2):

Правильный вариант - использование `HAVING` вместо `WHERE`.

`WHERE` не работает по результирующим столбцам, оно смотрит "напрямую" в БД, а `HAVING` фильтрует уже полученные после `WHERE` данные.

P.S. пошел подтягивать SQL.

Comment: Мы всегда рады вам помочь